# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{i^n}{2^n}=0$ Why?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{i^n}{2^n}$

I am having difficulties to understand this expression. The first step I would do is $(\frac{i}{2})^n$ but i do not know why this would converge to $0$. Thanks in advance for helpful comments. My problem is I dont know how to evaluate $(\frac{i}{2})^n$. I do not have a feeling of what it might be...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: for a complex sequence $\{z_n\}_{n\ge0}$, prove from the [epsilon-delta definition of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Definition) that $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=0$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}|z_n|=0$.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. I realize now, however, I should have called it epsilon-N.

Answer (score 2):

You have that

$$\left\lvert\frac{i^n}{2^n}\right\rvert=\frac{1}{2^n}\to0$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Why do you take the absolute value and why is it legit to use?

Comment: @mathsdummie1234 Look at the definition of the limit

Comment: I know, but why can we use it here? Is it than in fact we use it always but for real analysis it does not make any sense since absolute value of a is a

Comment: @mathsdummie1234 well we are working with the modulus of a complex number, which is what the limit is defined in terms of. So recall that $\frac{i^n}{2^n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ is defined as having that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N>0$, such that for all $n\geq N$, $\left\lvert\frac{i^n}{2^n}\right\rvert<\varepsilon$. But notice that since $\left\lvert\frac{i^n}{2^n}\right\rvert=\frac{1}{2^n}$, this is **equivalent** to having that $\frac{1}{2^n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: great thanks! Yeah we kinda using a mapping into real numbers and then calculate the limit.

Comment: @mathsdummie1234 Would you be happier with $\left\lvert\frac{i^n}{2^n}-0\right\rvert=\frac{1}{2^n} \lt \epsilon$  when $n > -\log_2(\epsilon)$?

Comment: Thanks @Henry works as well